# Fix position of responsive image in responsive header, next to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The idea of this is to have a responsive header with text and an image element, which sit on a fixed background image. 
I've tried to do this with bootstrap columns, which works on desktop to come out the way I want it. On smaller devices however, the bootstrap media queries do exactly what they are supposed to do and break the columns up to be displayed below each other.
I am out of ideas for this. I know I need to fix the image element somehow to stay consistently on the bottom end of the container, but since the entire thing is responsive I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Here is what I have so far, but this is not the solution. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
  <section class="section swatch-black section-text-shadow section-inner-shadow">
    <div class="background-media" style="background-image: url('http://some-url.com/home-intro.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment:fixed; background-position: 50% 60%;"> </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-left element-normal-top element-normal-bottom">
            <h1 class="bigger hairline bordered-normal element-tall-top"> Header Text<br>
              <strong>More Text </strong> </h1>
            <p class="lead"> Even more text </p>
          <a href="someurl.html" class="scroll-to-id btn btn-link btn-lg element-no-top element-normal-bottom"> learn more </a>
          <a href="someurl.html" class="scroll-to-id btn btn-link btn-lg element-no-top element-normal-bottom"> contact us </a> </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <img src="assets/images/uploads/test.png" style="position:relative; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 150px;">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image: This is what it's supposed to look like]

Comment: do you have an example of what it should look like and how it should behave? I'm having trouble visualizing this in my mind

Comment: updated question with image. I hope this helps.

Comment: so what happens on a small device? the text and buttons go on top, and the image goes below? The iPhones are the image element? so you want the iPhones to stay to the right side of the text even on a small device?

Comment: correct. This is not so important for iPhone, because I will most likely end up hiding the image of the phones there anyway. But on iPad they still should sit next to each other.

Comment: That's where my issue is: I can't get them to scale down in size without having them in the bootstrap column, but in the bootstrap column the text and images get separated on smaller devices.

Comment: do you want a solution with bootstrap or are you open to custom css? I don't use bootstrap much but I can help you with plain css

Comment: open to anything at this point. If you have a solution I'm all ears.

Comment: Maybe use col-xs-6 instead of col-md-6 and add media queries to lower font-size on smaller screens?

Comment: you can set up your own column structure. Here's an example that I made for you real quick: http://jsfiddle.net/97wswqvr/

Comment: That's perfect! If you add it as the answer I'll mark it as complete. You're awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set up your own column structure. Here's an example that I made for you real quick: 
http://jsfiddle.net/97wswqvr/

this will need more work obviously, depending on the rest of your header text/buttons etc... but its a good place to start

html

```
<header>
    <div class='content col col-1-2'>
        <div>
            text text text
        </div>
        <div>
            text text text
        </div>
        <div>
            text text text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col col-1-2 img'>
        <img class='col' src='http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/8459/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone/compare/iphone-compare-bbh-201411?wid=254&hei=210&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1416449205305'/>
    </div>
</header>
```

css

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;

}
header {
    background-image: url(http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-85/data1/images/southtyrol350698.jpg);
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
}
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.col-1-2 {
    width: 45%;
}
.img {
}
img {
    width: 70%;
}
```